# "Daily conversations" vs. "daily conversation"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, grammatical-number, nouns, programming

I am currently programming my own blog system to share knowledge about the Microsoft technology ASP.NET MVC, because I am rather passionate about web software development. I thought of calling it *Daily Conversations with ASP.NET MVC*. However, since English is not my mother tongue, I am not sure whether the title is grammatically correct — should it be *Conversation* or *Conversations*?

Comment: you don't want to call your blog **Daily Conversation with ASP.NET MVC**. its too boring.. try something else like say: **ASP.NET MVC Daily TalkFest**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are correct, however, "Conversation" has the implication that there is only one conversation with ASP.NET MVC, where as "Conversations" implies that there will be an unlimited amount of conversation and discussion per day on this site. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to think about it: Do you consider the conversations to be discrete, isolatable things (conversations) or more of a fluid, amorphous thing that's hard to delineate (conversation)? In short, is it like counting objects or measuring a liquid?

Comment: Since every single blog post is a self-contained thing, I will go for *"Conversations"*. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be saying Daily Conversations ***on*** (or about) ASP.Net.

To have a conversation ***with*** something implies it is listening and may possibly respond. I don't believe ASP.Net is having a conversation with you. It's never talked back to me.

Comment: That's a point. Sadly, it did neither for me!